# R tcl tk: How do I pass a variable to a button command?

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

How would I pass the value of `num` in a command function of a button?

```
f.frame <- tktoplevel()

numIDs = 50;
bs = list();
OnPress <- function (inum) { print (inum) }
for (num in 1:numIDs) {
    bs[[num]] <- tkbutton (f.frame, command = "OnPress num");
    tkpack (bs[[num]]);
}
```

Comment: I think the only way to make this work is to create a list (or environment), which you populate with different functions (one for each button that differ only in what number they have as a formal argument). The issue is lazy evaluation: R won't run the function specified in command (or evaluate any arguments passed to it) until the button is pushed. Someone else may know a better way to handle this, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a factory function that returns a function of no arguments:

```
makepresser=function(n){force(n);function(){cat("Hit me ",n," times\n")}}
```

in case you've not seen this before, it lets you do:

```
> m1 = makepresser(1)
> m1()
Hit me  1  times
> m2 = makepresser(9)
> m2()
Hit me  9  times
```

then its as simple as:

```
f.frame <- tktoplevel()
bs = list()
for(i in 1:10){
   bs[[i]]=tkbutton(f.frame,command=makepresser(i))
   tkpack(bs[[i]])
}
```

The factory function creates a function *closure* of no arguments which keeps the value of `n` when it was constructed (the `force` function is needed here or you get bitten by lazy evaluation).